# batch concatenating of png images to single file

Tags: batch-file, macros, image-manipulation, applescript

I want create texture atlas(matrix of images) from multiple images.Is their any applescript that can create image matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) set of tools? There is an [example](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#append) showing the use of the -append and +append options of the convert program that shows how to append images into rows and columns of the destination image.

Comment: Good one. But I am working with a MACOSX, behind a proxy, which is not allowing to download any binaries.

Comment: `convert image1.png image2.png image3.png -append stack.png` will create stack.png with the three input images layed out from top to bottom. Use +append for laying out left to right.

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick, as suggested by Jeff, really is a good solution. However, I would recommend the `montage` command instead of `convert`. Whareas `convert` allows for creation of horizontally or vertically aligned stacks, `montage` together with the `-tile` switch lets you create a matrix of images with a defined number of rows and columns.

Resources:

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php

http://mariovalle.name/postprocessing/ImageTools.html#assemble